# Why i still get into login prompt despite buggy module is loaded and kernel panic cmd is issued

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto, panic

i want to simulate a kernel panic on beaglebone yocto during system startup , i wrote a simple script with below content

```
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

and have the systemd run it during startup
i saw the kernel panic not syncing message
but i still can get into login prompt and login successfully.
i was expecting yocto linux to hang when kernel panic message is appeared

btw i also try the following code and load it as out of tree module

```
static int crash_module_init(void)

{
    printk("CRASHING MODULE IS LOADED\n");
    int *p = 0;

    printk("%d\n", *p);

    return 0;
}

static void crash_module_exit(void)
{
   printk("crash module exiting\n");
}

module_init(crash_module_init);
module_exit(crash_module_exit);
```

it still can get into login prompt and i can login successfully.
I was expecting the entire system hang when kernel panic message is observed , anyone know why it not hang as i thought it will be?
P/S :I intended to develop test cases for this boot failure scenario that why i try to perform a failed boot test using any known method to my knowledge.

Buggy module logging

```
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","hello: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel."
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","CRASHING MODULE IS LOADED !"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","alert","kernel","Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","alert","kernel","pgd = 9b2ccf23"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","alert","kernel","[00000000] *pgd=00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT ARM"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","Modules linked in: hello(O+)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","CPU: 0 PID: 85 Comm: systemd-modules Tainted: G           O     4.15.18-yocto-standard #1"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","PC is at init_module+0x20/0x3c [hello]"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","LR is at wake_up_klogd+0x54/0x88"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","pc : [<bf000020>]    lr : [<c016b994>]    psr: 60060013"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","sp : de55fdb8  ip : de55fca8  fp : de55fdcc"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","r10: 00000028  r9 : de559ca4  r8 : 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","r7 : de559c80  r6 : de559440  r5 : ffffe000  r4 : 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000000  r1 : 00000000  r0 : 0000001b"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment none"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","Control: 10c5387d  Table: 9d068019  DAC: 00000051"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","Process systemd-modules (pid: 85, stack limit = 0xd41915b1)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","Stack: (0xde55fdb8 to 0xde560000)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fda0:                                                       bf000000 ffffe000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fdc0: de55fe3c de55fdd0 c0101b70 bf00000c dfeb59a8 c020d794 de55fdfc de55fde8"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fde0: c020b78c 0009e59a 20060013 c0257064 de55fe3c de55fe00 c0257064 c02539cc"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fe00: 00000001 c0248d7c de559440 00000001 00000001 bf002000 de55ff40 bf002000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fe20: de55ff40 de559440 de559c80 00000001 de55fe64 de55fe40 c019dadc c0101a48"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fe40: 00000001 de559c80 de55fe64 bf002000 de55ff40 00000001 de55ff1c de55fe68"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fe60: c019cf7c c019da7c bf00200c 00007fff bf002000 c01998e8 de55ff34 b6dd0734"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fe80: 00000000 bf0021dc 00000022 00000000 c0f2b8d8 c0a05094 bf002048 e00c5000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fea0: c02709d4 c047a620 00000003 c047b36c 00000aec 00000000 00000000 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fec0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 7fffffff 00000000 b6dd0734 00000005"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ff00: 0000017b c0107b68 de55e000 00000000 de55ffa4 de55ff20 c019d1cc c019b1b8"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ff20: 7fffffff 00000000 00000003 de55ff3c de55ff40 e00c5000 00000aec 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ff40: e00c50fa e00c5000 00000aec e00c57cc e00c5708 e00c55d4 00003000 000030d0"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ff60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 000002cc 00000011 00000012 0000000c 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ff80: 00000007 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 de55ffa8"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ffa0: c0107940 c019d140 00000000 00000001 00000005 b6dd0734 00000000 0042a2b8"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ffc0: 00000000 00000001 00000000 0000017b 00000000 00417d78 00000000 0042d758"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ffe0: bee3c3f0 bee3c3e0 b6dc8df4 b6d4d530 60060010 00000005 00000000 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<bf000020>] (init_module [hello]) from [<c0101b70>] (do_one_initcall+0x134/0x15c)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c0101b70>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c019dadc>] (do_init_module+0x6c/0x1f4)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c019dadc>] (do_init_module) from [<c019cf7c>] (load_module+0x1dd0/0x1e34)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c019cf7c>] (load_module) from [<c019d1cc>] (SyS_finit_module+0x98/0xa0)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c019d1cc>] (SyS_finit_module) from [<c0107940>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x54)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","Code: e8bd4000 e3a04000 e59f0014 eb45b37c (e5941000) "
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","info","kernel","EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:26", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","---[ end trace 47c7d6929dcdcaf6 ]---"
```

echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger logging

```
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","info","kernel","sysrq: SysRq : Trigger a crash"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","alert","kernel","Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","alert","kernel","pgd = f584d656"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","alert","kernel","[00000000] *pgd=9d1c2831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","Internal error: Oops: 817 [#2] PREEMPT ARM"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","Modules linked in: hello(O+)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","CPU: 0 PID: 166 Comm: system-ini Tainted: G      D    O     4.15.18-yocto-standard #1"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","PC is at sysrq_handle_crash+0x30/0x3c"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","LR is at sysrq_handle_crash+0x2c/0x3c"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","pc : [<c0585b0c>]    lr : [<c0585b08>]    psr: 600b0013"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","sp : dd15fec0  ip : dd15fec0  fp : dd15fed4"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","r10: 00000000  r9 : dd15e000  r8 : 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","r7 : 00000063  r6 : 0000000f  r5 : c0f21fe4  r4 : 00000001"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000000  r1 : 00000000  r0 : c0f21080"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment none"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","Control: 10c5387d  Table: 9d108019  DAC: 00000051"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","Process system-ini (pid: 166, stack limit = 0xf5a861d1)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","Stack: (0xdd15fec0 to 0xdd160000)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fec0: c0f86e50 c0f21fe4 dd15fefc dd15fed8 c0586080 c0585ae8 00000002 de32c000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","fee0: 00000001 00000000 00000000 dd15e000 dd15ff14 dd15ff00 c05864ec c0585ff4"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ff00: c0586484 de32c000 dd15ff34 dd15ff18 c02cb968 c0586490 c02cb8f0 00000002"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ff20: 00104b18 dd15ff80 dd15ff4c dd15ff38 c026a3c8 c02cb8fc de4e7480 00000002"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ff40: dd15ff7c dd15ff50 c026a584 c026a3ac c0289090 c0288fe0 de4e7480 de4e7480"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ff60: 00104b18 00000002 c0107b68 dd15e000 dd15ffa4 dd15ff80 c026a72c c026a4c4"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ff80: 00000000 00000000 00000002 00104b18 b6f40d98 00000004 00000000 dd15ffa8"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ffa0: c0107940 c026a6e8 00000002 00104b18 00000001 00104b18 00000002 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ffc0: 00000002 00104b18 b6f40d98 00000004 00104b18 00000002 00000000 00000000"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","ffe0: 00000064 be819990 b6e69da8 b6ec2cb4 600b0010 00000001 9fef6861 9fef6c61"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c0585b0c>] (sysrq_handle_crash) from [<c0586080>] (__handle_sysrq+0x98/0x138)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c0586080>] (__handle_sysrq) from [<c05864ec>] (write_sysrq_trigger+0x68/0x78)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c05864ec>] (write_sysrq_trigger) from [<c02cb968>] (proc_reg_write+0x78/0x88)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c02cb968>] (proc_reg_write) from [<c026a3c8>] (__vfs_write+0x28/0x48)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c026a3c8>] (__vfs_write) from [<c026a584>] (vfs_write+0xcc/0x158)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c026a584>] (vfs_write) from [<c026a72c>] (SyS_write+0x50/0x88)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","[<c026a72c>] (SyS_write) from [<c0107940>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x54)"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","Code: e5834000 f57ff04e ebee3e32 e3a03000 (e5c34000) "
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","warning","kernel","---[ end trace 47c7d6929dcdcaf7 ]---"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","kern","emerg","kernel","---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","daemon","info","sh"," cat: '/sys/devices/platform/ocp/481d8000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/life_time': No such file or directory"
"2020-12-21","01:44:27", "beaglebone-yocto","daemon","info","sh"," cat: '/sys/devices/platform/ocp/481d8000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/pre_eol_info': No such file or directory"
```

Comment: Because it is not crashing the kernel.

Comment: @Oleksandr Than how? I already trigger kernel panic manually, if this is not right way, what is the right way?